# Excel xlsx password - remove or crack?

Tags: excel, bash

I have a excel file and set a password by 'bashing' at they keyboard..

I was basically testing it and pressed everything.. Got me thinking, Is they a way to crack/remove the password?

I'm not on about just a sheet, I mean the actual file..

When I click to open the xlsx file a pop up box comes up asking for the password.. Easy way around it?

Comment: Yes, don't do silly things like "bash at the keyboard" :-)

Comment: Have you not checked Google? http://superuser.com/questions/58263/remove-password-from-an-excel-document

Comment: Excel asks for password verification when you set it. How did you manage to bash at keyboard INDENTICALLY TWICE IN A ROW? :D
Alsho high five for "bash" tag.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. An `xlsx` (which is essentially a `zip` file) uses a far superior encryption model than earlier Excel formats (e.g. `xls`). In short, the *whole* file is encrypted as opposed to a password hash being embedded in an otherwise readable file.

Your only hope is to write a brute force cracker that mimics the bashing behaviour you describe. (e.g. unlikely that you have mixed case etc.).